# Regex to match URL with specific query string param

Tags: regex

I am using this regex `.*\?(a\=([0-9]{3,4}))` to match any URLs with the query string ?a={{a random number here}}. It should only match a query string with 3 or 4 digits

E.g.

```
http://www.test.com/test/test-test-test/?a=12
http://www.test.com/test-test/news/?a=734
http://www.test.com/test/?a=0987
http://www.test.com/test/test-test-test/?a=90235
```

My regex should match the second and third links as they contain a query string 3 or 4 digits.

I am using this tool http://www.regexpal.com/ and so far, it only highlights the second link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
.+\/\?a=([0-9]{3,4})$
```

- `/.+\/\?a=([0-9]{3,4})$/gm`
- `.+` matches any character (except newline)
- `Quantifier: +` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `\/` matches the character / literally
- `\?` matches the character ? literally
- `a=` matches the characters a= literally (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing group `([0-9]{3,4})`
- `[0-9]{3,4}` match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: {3,4} Between 3 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- `$` assert position at end of a line

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/sP0lR3/1

And as a visual representation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m7PsbFiJGNdAzZts)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The visual representation was super helpful too. I will check the debuggex demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=\d{3,4}$
```

[Regex101 Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iJ9fY9/2)